# Finding the overlap between two data frames in R, how can I make my code more efficient?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I have two dataframes in R.  In the first one I have two columns one is called "chr" and the other "position"; in the second dataframe I have three columns one is again "chr", other "start" and another one "end". I want to select those rows in the first dataframe in which chr value is the same as the second data frame, but also whose "position" is in the interval start-end of the second data frame.

For that I have written a function in R that gives me the desired output but it is very slow when I run it with huge data frames.

```
# My DataFrames are:

bed <- data.frame(Chr = c(rep("chr1",4),rep("chr2",3),rep("chr3",1)),
                  x1 = c(5,20,44,67,5,20,44,20),
                  x3=c(12,43,64,94,12,43,64,63))

snv <- data.frame(Chr = c(rep("chr1",6),rep("chr3",6)),
                  position = c(5,18,46,60,80,90,21,60,75,80,84,87))

# My function is:

get_overlap <- function(df, position, chrom){
  overlap <- FALSE
  for (row in 1:nrow(df)){
    chr = df[row, 1]
    start = df[row, 2]
    end = df[row, 3]
    if(chr == chrom & position %in% seq(start, end)){
      overlap <- TRUE
    }
    }
  return(overlap)
}

# The code is:

overlap_vector = c()
for (row in 1:nrow(snv)){
  chrom = snv[row, 1]
  position = snv[row, 2]
  overlap <- get_overlap(bed, position, chrom)
  overlap_vector <- c(overlap_vector, overlap)
}

print(snv[overlap_vector,])
```

How can I make this more efficient? I have never worked with hash tables, can that be the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's a more elegant [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution, but this works. First I load the package.

```r
# Load package
library(data.table)
```

Then, I define the data tables

```r
# Define data tables
bed <- data.table(Chr = c(rep("chr1",4),rep("chr2",3),rep("chr3",1)),
                  start = c(5,20,44,67,5,20,44,20),
                  end = c(12,43,64,94,12,43,64,63))

snv <- data.table(Chr = c(rep("chr1",6),rep("chr3",6)),
                  position = c(5,18,46,60,80,90,21,60,75,80,84,87))
```

Here, I do a non-equi join on `position` and `start`/`end`, and an equal join on `Chr`. I assume you want to keep all columns, so specified them in the `j` argument and omitted those rows without matches.

```r
na.omit(bed[snv, 
            .(Chr, start = x.start, end = x.end, position = i.position), 
            on = c("start <= position", "end >= position", "Chr == Chr")])
#>     Chr start end position
#> 1: chr1     5  12        5
#> 2: chr1    44  64       46
#> 3: chr1    44  64       60
#> 4: chr1    67  94       80
#> 5: chr1    67  94       90
#> 6: chr3    20  63       21
#> 7: chr3    20  63       60
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

### Edit

A quick benchmarking shows that Nathan's solution is about as twice as fast!

```r
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 NathanWren() 1.684392 1.729557 1.819263 1.751520 1.787829 5.138546   100
   Lyngbakr() 3.336902 3.395528 3.603376 3.441933 3.496131 7.720925   100
```

Comment: You could add the `dplyr`-flavor version to the benchmarks: `left_join(bed, snv) %>% filter(position >= x1, position <= x3)`

Answer (score 3):

The `data.table` package is great for fast merging of tables.  It also comes with a vectorized `between` function for just this type of task.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert the data.frames to data.tables
setDT(bed)
setDT(snv)

# Use the join syntax for data.table, then filter for the desired rows
overlap_dt <- bed[
  snv,
  on = "Chr",
  allow.cartesian = TRUE # many-to-many matching
][
  between(position, lower = x1, upper = x3)
]

overlap_dt
#     Chr x1 x3 position
# 1: chr1  5 12        5
# 2: chr1 44 64       46
# 3: chr1 44 64       60
# 4: chr1 67 94       80
# 5: chr1 67 94       90
# 6: chr3 20 63       21
# 7: chr3 20 63       60
```

Comment: Nice idea to join then filter! Probably faster than the non-equi join I used, too.